# DatePickerDialog cannot get in onDateSet

Tags: android

Here is the code. I have a Log.e to check if the program go into the onDateSet function, and found that it doesn't.

Here is the code:

```
private void datePicker(){
    //Calendar datePickercal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(ContentInput.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Log.e(ErrorTag, "date picker: " + year + " " + month + " " + dayOfMonth);
            cal.set(year,month+1,dayOfMonth);
        }
    }
    ,cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    ,cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    ,cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    dialog.show();
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                timePicker();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you call datePicker() somewhere?

Comment: yes. I have a switch button, when it is on, it calls datePicker()

Comment: You're overriding the default behavior for the positive button, which is where that callback is invoked. Move your `timePicker()` call to `onDateSet()`, and get rid of the `setButton()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. ThankS Mike, It is working now!   How do I mark your answer is the correct answer here?

Comment: Cool. You can't accept a comment, though. Gimme a minute, and I'll post a proper answer.

Comment: Can you help me one more question? So, I have a timepicker dialog, then, I pick, for example, 23:00, and put it into calendar, then I check the calendar time, it shows 11:00, which is 12 hours earlier, why is that?

Comment: Are you using `Calendar.HOUR`, or `HOUR_OF_DAY`?

Comment: YA YA. I changed to HOUR_OF_DAY and it works! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DatePickerDialog` invokes its `OnDateSetListener` callback in the positive button click. In fact, `DatePickerDialog` sets up that callback with its own call to `setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, ...)`. Your call to that method is overriding that, so the `OnDateSetListener` is never called.

Move your `timePicker()` call to the `onDateSet()` method, and remove the `dialog.setButton()` call.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for date picker

```
 calendar1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dateflag = "from";
            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

        }
    });


public static class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, 2017, 01, 01);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
        populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
    }

    public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        if (dateflag.equals("from")) {
            from_date_ext.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
        } else {
            to_date_ext.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

        }
    }

}
```